# fixed header in cordova

Tags: html, css, cordova

I'm trying to fix my header to the top, so that if the user scrolls trough a list the search input field and the title bars stays on top of the screen. But at the moment the header scrolls up with the content in the body...

This is what i have:

```
<body ng-controller="SearchCtrl" class="animated fadeIn">
    <div class="bar bar-header fixed bar-assertive" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
      <a href="index.html"class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left smaller button-clear button-white"></a>
          <h1 class="title">Suche</h1>
      </div>
      <label class="item item-input has-header fixed" style="margin-top: 5px;">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Solothurn durchsuchen..." name="text" ng-model="searchBox.storeName">
    </label>
    <br>
```

The fixed class is:

`position: fixed;`

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try adding top: 0 to it? Might as well add left:0 and right: 0 as well if it is full width.

Answer (score 1):

Just to test it add `!important` to your css fixed class. One of your other classes may be overriding/cascading over it. If it fixes it then you need to do something in your style sheet to make the `position: fixed` rule take precedence over the other position rule that is getting applied so you can then drop the `!important` as it is cleaner and lighter if the CSS cascades correctly the first time.